# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error

Tags: java

I am working on a robot maze where the robot finds the target without bumping into walls. As a "backtrack" method, I need the robot to go in the opposite direction as it did when it first came across a junction. This is my code:

```
import uk.ac.warwick.dcs.maze.logic.IRobot;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Explorer {

    private int pollRun = 0; // Incremented after each pass.
    private RobotData robotData; // Data store for junctions.
    private ArrayList<Integer> nonWallDirections;   
    private ArrayList<Integer> passageDirections; 
    private ArrayList<Integer> beenbeforeDirections;
    private Random random = new Random();
    int [] directions = {IRobot.AHEAD, IRobot.LEFT, IRobot.RIGHT, IRobot.BEHIND};

    public void controlRobot (IRobot robot) {

        // On the first move of the first run of a new maze.
        if ((robot.getRuns() == 0) && (pollRun ==0))
            robotData = new RobotData();
        pollRun++; /* Increment poll run so that the data is not reset 
                        each time the robot moves. */

        int exits = nonwallExits(robot);
        int direction;

        nonWallDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        passageDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        beenbeforeDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // Adding each direction to the appropriate state ArrayList.
            for(int item : directions) {
                if(robot.look(item) != IRobot.WALL) {
                    nonWallDirections.add(item);
                }
            }

            for(int item : directions) {
                if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.PASSAGE) {
                    passageDirections.add(item);
                }
            }

            for(int item : directions) {
                if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.BEENBEFORE) {
                    beenbeforeDirections.add(item);
                }
            }

        // Calling the appropriate method depending on the number of exits.
        if (exits < 2) {
            direction = deadEnd(robot);
        } else if (exits == 2) {
            direction = corridor(robot);
        } else {
            direction = junction(robot);
            robotData.addJunction(robot);
            robotData.printJunction(robot);
        } 

        robot.face(direction);
    }


    /* The specification advised to have to seperate controls: Explorer and Backtrack
        and a variable explorerMode to switch between them.
        Instead, whenever needed I shall call this backtrack method.
        If at a junction, the robot will head back the junction as to when it first approached it.
        When at a deadend or corridor, it will follow the beenbefore squares until it
        reaches an unexplored path. */
    public int backtrack (IRobot robot) {

        if (nonwallExits(robot) > 2) {
            return robotData.reverseHeading(robot);
        } else {
                do {
                    return nonWallDirections.get(0);
                } while (nonwallExits(robot) == 1);
        }

    }


    //  Deadend method makes the robot follow the only nonwall exit.
    public int deadEnd (IRobot robot) {

        return backtrack(robot);

    }


    /* Corridor method will make the robot follow the one and only passage. 
        The exception is at the start. Sometimes, the robot will start with 
        two passages available to it in which case it will choose one randomly.
        If there is no passage, it will follow the beenbefore squares
        until it reaches an unexplored path.*/
    public int corridor (IRobot robot) {

        if (passageExits(robot) == 1) {
            return passageDirections.get(0);
        } else if (passageExits(robot) == 2) {
            int randomPassage = random.nextInt(passageDirections.size());
            return passageDirections.get(randomPassage);
        } else {
                return backtrack(robot);
        }
    }


    /* Junction method states if there is more than one passage, it will randomly select one.
        This applies to crossroads as well as essentially they are the same.
        If there is no passage, it will follow the beenbefore squares until it reaches an unexplored
        path. */
    public int junction(IRobot robot) {

        if (passageExits(robot) == 1) {
            return passageDirections.get(0);
        } else if (passageExits(robot) > 1) {
            int randomPassage = random.nextInt(passageDirections.size());
            return passageDirections.get(randomPassage);
        } else {
            return backtrack(robot);
        }

    }


    // Calculates number of exits.
    private int nonwallExits (IRobot robot) {

        int nonwallExits = 0;

        for(int item : directions) {
            if(robot.look(item) != IRobot.WALL) {
               nonwallExits++;
            }
        }

        return nonwallExits;
    }


    // Calculates number of passages.
    private int passageExits (IRobot robot) {

        int passageExits = 0;

        for(int item : directions) {
            if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.PASSAGE) {
                passageExits++;
            }
        }

        return passageExits;
    }


    // Calculates number of beenbefores.
    private int beenbeforeExits (IRobot robot) {

        int beenbeforeExits = 0;

        for(int item : directions) {
            if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.PASSAGE) {
                beenbeforeExits++;
            }
        }

        return beenbeforeExits;
    }

    // Resets Junction Counter in RobotData class.
    public int reset() {

        return robotData.resetJunctionCounter();

    }
}

class RobotData { 

    /* It was advised in the specification to include the variable:
        private static int maxJunctions = 10000;
        However, as I am not using arrays, but ArrayLists, I do not 
        need this. */
    private static int junctionCounter = 0;
    private ArrayList<Junction> junctionList = new ArrayList<Junction>();
    private Iterator<Junction> junctionIterator = junctionList.iterator();

    // Resets the Junction counter.
    public int resetJunctionCounter() {

        return junctionCounter = 0;

    }


    // Adds the current junction to the list of arrays.
    public void addJunction(IRobot robot) {

        Junction newJunction = new Junction(robot.getLocation().x, robot.getLocation().y, robot.getHeading());
        junctionList.add(newJunction);
        junctionCounter++;

    }


    // Gets the junction counter for Junction info method in Junction class.
    public int getJunctionCounter (IRobot robot) {

        return junctionCounter;
    }


    // Prints Junction info.
    public void printJunction(IRobot robot) {

        String course = "";
        switch (robot.getHeading()) {
            case IRobot.NORTH:
                course = "NORTH";
                break;
            case IRobot.EAST:
                course = "EAST";
                break;
            case IRobot.SOUTH:
                course = "SOUTH";
                break;
            case IRobot.WEST:
                course = "WEST";
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Junction " + junctionCounter + " (x=" + robot.getLocation().x + ", y=" + robot.getLocation().y +") heading " + course);

    }

    /* Iterates through the junction arrayList to find the 
        heading of the robot when it first approached the junction. */
    public int searchJunction(IRobot robot) {

        Junction currentJunction = junctionIterator.next(); 
        while (junctionIterator.hasNext()) {
            if ((((currentJunction.x)==(robot.getLocation().x))) && ((currentJunction.y)==(robot.getLocation().y))) 
                break;
        }

        return currentJunction.arrived;
    }


    // Returns the reverse of the heading the robot had when first approaching the junction.
    public int reverseHeading(IRobot robot) {

        int firstHeading = searchJunction(robot);
        int reverseHeading = 1; // Random integer to Iniitalise variable.

        switch (firstHeading) {
                    case IRobot.NORTH:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                    break;

                    case IRobot.EAST:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                    break;

                    case IRobot.SOUTH:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                    break;

                    case IRobot.WEST:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                    break;
                }

        return reverseHeading;

    }

}


class Junction {

    int x;
    int y;
    int arrived;

    public Junction(int xcoord, int ycoord, int course) {

        x = xcoord;
        y = ycoord;
        arrived = course;

    }

}
```

Whenever it is backtracking and reaches a junction it has already visited, it freezes and this comes up.

```
`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at uk.ac.warwick.dcs.maze.controllers.PolledControllerWrapper.start(PolledControllerWrapper.java:70)
    at uk.ac.warwick.dcs.maze.logic.ControllerThread.run(ControllerThread.java:46)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at RobotData.searchJunction(Explorer.java:242)
    at RobotData.reverseHeading(Explorer.java:255)
    at Explorer.backtrack(Explorer.java:74)
    at Explorer.junction(Explorer.java:122)
    at Explorer.controlRobot(Explorer.java:56)
    ... 5 more`
```

Comment: Please do not deface your question by removing your code, error message or other pertinent data, as this makes the question completely worthless for future visitors. I have rolled back your question to its previous state, and will do it again if you try to deface it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your `searchJunction()` is right or safe, the ConcurrentModificationException might be thrown due to the incorrect iterator through `junctionList` . The problem should be more about the iterator rather than reflection.

You might try:

1. `private Iterator<Junction> junctionIterator = junctionList.iterator();` doesn't make much sense since the list is empty when initialize a RobotData object. Try to move it into searchJunction()
2. Check `hasNext()` first then invoke `next()`

   ```
   public int searchJunction(IRobot robot) {
       Iterator<Junction> junctionIterator = junctionList.iterator();
       while (junctionIterator.hasNext()) {
           Junction currentJunction = junctionIterator.next(); 
           if ((((currentJunction.x)==(robot.getLocation().x))) && ((currentJunction.y)==(robot.getLocation().y))) 
               break;
       }

       return currentJunction.arrived;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! you're a genius! I have one more question. Is it possible to get the robot run the maze once, remember the correct route and then on the second run take the correct route? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: How about using a LinkedList-type instance variable to save the correct path: IRobot.AHEAD/IRobot.LEFT/.....   ? And if the maze might change, you need to design some mapping mechanism to evaluate the identity of maze when return the saved solution.

Comment: hmm I've never heard of LinkedList. Mind going into a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that issue is in following code -

```
`public int searchJunction(IRobot robot) {

    Junction currentJunction = junctionIterator.next(); 
    while (junctionIterator.hasNext()) {
        if ((((currentJunction.x)==(robot.getLocation().x))) && ((currentJunction.y)==(robot.getLocation().y))) 
            break;
    }

    return currentJunction.arrived;
}
```

You are calling  junctionIterator.next() before calling junctionIterator.hasNext(). Iterator specification says that you should call next() only after calling hasNext()